# spring social google: people API 403 Forbidden due to Legacy People API

Tags: google-api, spring-social, spring-social-google

I've got project, where I have to login through google sign in. I have created google project. Set up client/secret keys. I got to the point where I'm making post request to my web app server and sending there the accessToken:

```
OAuth2ConnectionFactory<Google> connectionFactory = (OAuth2ConnectionFactory<Google>) connectionFactoryLocator().getConnectionFactory(Google.class);
AccessGrant accessGrant = new AccessGrant(accessToken);
Connection<Google> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
```

The request is:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Authorization: Bearer etc.

Here I got exception: 403 Forbidden. I had to manually track what the actual request is done and made rest request manually to replicate the issue with given headers.

Here is the result I'm getting:

> "code": 403, "message": "Legacy People API has not been used in
>   project ... before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=...
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry."

First of all the link fails to load. I didn't find any "Legacy People API". Only new People API.

I wonder if there is any solution to this problem? I have enabled People API and waited for long enough but the same error remains.

EDIT 1:
I think the project spring-social is dead. Will rewrite login logic and kick spring-social out of it..

Comment: Hey! Same story here... The feature stopped working at the end of October.

As a temporary solution, I created another project in Google Console with absolutely the same approach (APIs and etc). It works, but I would like to use the original project.

Anyway, still looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

ME TOO . this my problem. I'm waiting 6 hours

"code": 403, "message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project

Comment: I have recently found out that the spring social project is dead. Not sure if you are also using it. Will have to rewrite the login logic without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Google Identity Platform [OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) instead of the [Legacy People API](https://developers.google.com/people/legacy).

Comment: Ok just found out that spring-social is not supported anymore. Dead.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Which is the replacement library for the spring-social. What are the changes do we need to make?

Comment: @KrishnaShetty, I think it is now inside spring-security latest version. I will have to refactor the code for login.. Or it could be made independent on spring, but using provided by google/and other social networks api.